# DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object

Tags: python, selenium

Я хотел написать на Selenium'e открытие Instagram в браузере Chrome, но мне сообщает что executable_path устарел, однако в интернете я не нашёл подробной информации по данной проблеме. Вот мой код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time

url = "https://www.instagram.com/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\namva\\PycharmProjects\\seleniumlessons\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe")

try:
    driver.get(url=url)
    time.sleep(5)
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

Как я могу выйти из данной ситуации?

Comment: Вы разобрались или вам нужна еще помощь?

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time

chrome_options = Options()
driver1 = Service("C:\\Users\\namva\\PycharmProjects\\seleniumlessons\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

url = "https://www.instagram.com/"

try:
    driver.get(url=url)
    time.sleep(5)
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip3 install -U selenium
pip3 install webdriver-manager - скачай вот это.

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


web = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

web.get("https:\\vk.com")
```

При запуске кода, ошибки про устаревший executable_path не будет возникать.